# Unable to locate package libsfml-audio1.5

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When "rosmake impromptu_buttons --rosdep-install", error msg:

```
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['impromptu_buttons'] to:
['impromptu_buttons']                        
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#Packages
sudo apt-get install libsfml-audio1.5
}}}
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr 
{{{
E: Unable to locate package libsfml-audio1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libsfml-audio1.5'

}}}
```

Looks like libsfml no longer supports Ubuntu10.10...... anyone run into this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9574/unable-to-locate-package-libsfml-audio1.5/) by [kexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/343/kexi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-28**:
@mjcarroll see the FAQ you're almost there.  (I lowered it for now ;-) )

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-26**:
Thanks @tfoote for the reformat.  When do I get the power to do that? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's because libsfml-audio has been updated to 1.6 in Ubuntu 10.10

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-audio1.6
```

Should install it for you.

You should also be able to update the https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk/kinect_utils/rosdep.yaml files to reflect this version change.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1